# Home page error "no Home CMS page configured or found"

Tags: cms

I have created a new CMS page and want to set it as my homepage.

I have tried to change my page through `System> Configuration> Web > CMS Homepage`, but I got the error message

> "There was no Home CMS page configured or found" in my frontend home page.

How can I fix for this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493271/magento-setting-the-default-homepage-store-when-you-have-multiple-stores

Comment: Try by Cleaning the cache in magento and also browser cache.

Answer (score 5):

- ***Possible reason***: The new CMS  page you created is not **Enabled**.
- ***Solution***: `Set Page Status -> Enable` || `Set Store View -> All Store View`

Answer (score 2):

In the admin you go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages

You will have to change to the website / store view that you want to change (the dropdown in the upper left corner). You will probably have to create a new CMS page if you want to have something different from your default home page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set it for the right store.
 And the page is active and available in this store.